# JPA Entity, JSON serialization, create the jpa entity class for json nested object

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson

I have Json object for which I want to create jpa entity class but not able to make it work. Pls help creating jpa entity class. I had model class which works fine reading/writing json file using jackson. However, not sure how to create the jpa entity class and its repository

```
"Mdata":{
    "gropus":{
          "groupA":["A","B","C"],
          "groupB":["X","Y","Z"],
          "groupC":["L","A","X"] 
     } 
}
```

Model which works fine for reading/writing json using jackson

```
class Mdata {
    @JsonProperty("gropus")
    private Group group;
     //with getter/setter
}

class Group {   
      List<String> groupA;   
      List<String> groupB;  
      List<String> groupC; 
     //with getter/setter 
}
```

Pls help me creating jpa entity class and its repository

Comment: You want to parse the JSON string and construct `Mdata` object?

Comment: I want to parse the json string using JPA so want to construct the jpa entity class so that i can query

Answer (score 0):

If your Json objects have same structure as Entities then you can create a single class which will represent both the Json and the Entity. For example like this:

```
@Entity
class Mdata {

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("gropus")
    private Group group;
    //with getter/setter
}

@Entity
class Group{

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;        

    @OneToMany
    List<String> groupA; 

    @OneToMany
    List<String> groupA; 

    @OneToMany 
    List<String> groupA;  
}
```

With this, you can use Jackson to parse a Json string to Json object, and because Json object can be also an Entity, you can simply pass it to JPA and execute your query against a database.

Comment: Thanks I will try with above JPA Entity class as well.So far i have tried with below entity class and it seems to be working...

Comment: @ioko can you please provide a more concrete example of how to use Jackson to parse a Json string to an Entity and use it to do the query? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,   property = "id")
    @Entity
    public class Mdata  {
    public Metadata() {
        //needed by Hibernagte
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonView(value={Views.Internal.class})
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("gropus")
    @Embedded
     private Group group;
   }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @Embeddable
    class Group {
        @ElementCollection
        column(name="gropA")
        List<String> groupA;
        @ElementCollection
        column(name="gropB")   
        List<String> groupB;
        @ElementCollection
        column(name="gropC")  
        List<String> groupC; 
       //with getter/setter 
     }
```

I will try your entity class and test. The above entity class creates below tables

```
insert into PUBLIC.Mdata_groupA(Mdata_id, groupA) values (?, ?)
insert into PUBLIC.Mdata_groupB(Mdata_id, groupB) values (?, ?)
insert into PUBLIC.Mdata_groupC(Mdata_id, groupC) values (?, ?)
```